# React js app doesn't render anything after setting up redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I created a react app with create-react-app and it was rendering the default page. I modified app.js to my needs and set up redux. After that when I run npm start command, it renders only an empty page and no error message in console.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Router, Route, Redirect } from "react-router";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {store} from "./store/index";
import Home from "./components/common/Home";
import {history} from './store/index'



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history} >
         <Route path='/home' Component={Home}></Route>
       </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {store} from "./store/index";
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import './css/index'
import { Router, Route, Redirect } from "react-router";

ReactDOM.render(

<App store={store}/>


, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

store.js

```
import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';



const getMiddleware =()=>{
 return applyMiddleware(thunk,createLogger())
}
export const history = createHistory();


export const store= createStore(rootReducer,getMiddleware());
```

reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    articles: []
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  return state;
};
export default rootReducer;
```

I couldn't identify where I am going wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be missing a default route for path "/". The only route present is for path ''/home".

Comment: even with default path "/" i get the same result

Comment: also is this a new app? looks like you're using an old version of react-router

Comment: also, probably not related but still worth mentioning, you're passing `store` as a props to `<App />` but you're not using it.. you're importing store as a static import in App.js

Comment: also... you're importing `history` from the store index file? what's that about

Comment: follow the react router 4 docs.. you'll have a much simpler time setting this up https://react-router.now.sh/

Comment: my react-router version is 4.3.1

Comment: this is a webapp? you should be importing from `react-router-dom`

Comment: yes this is a web-app

Comment: also what is `/css/index` ?

Comment: I am planning to import all css files into a index.js file and importing it in main index.js

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your `App.js` component in the following manner:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./components/common/Home";
```

Notice I did not use `react-router`, I used `react-router-dom`, that's what you should be using. `react-router` is the main or core library that powers `react-router-dom` and `react-router-dom-native`. use `react-router-dom`.

Notice I have no `store`, no `Provider` setup, we are going to leave that for your root `index.js` file. Now the rest of your `App` component would look like this:

```
const App = () => {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container">
       <BrowserRouter>
         <div>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
         </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now on to your root `index.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";

import App from "./components/App";
import reducers from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

That's where you place your `Provider` and `store`. I just eliminated the need for the `store.js` file, not necessary.

Now inside your first reducer, since you need some type of reducer for your app to boot up and not crash you can just write one like so inside of `reducers/index.js`:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

export default combineReducers({
  replaceMe: () => "howdy"
});
```

You now have a fully running error-less React-Redux application, you can move forward with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a really good reason for creating your own `history` object, use the BrowserRouter or HashRouter objects that are exported from `react-router-dom`

And as a matter of putting things in the right places.. import the store where you actually set it as a provider instead of importing it twice.

// app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store/index";
import Home from "./components/common/Home";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path='/home' Component={Home}></Route>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

// index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import './css/index'

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I made these changes..but still i see only empty page

Comment: try `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

Comment: Are you getting an empty page when running the dev server via `npm start` and going to localhost? or by serving the build folder somehow, somewhere